# How to pass a value from one viewcontroller to another UIObject

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hai I am very new to xcode now I need to pass a id value from loginViewController to Services UIObject page please help me to pass the value I expect the Complete or Sample code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry this is my very first question

Comment: Blocks,delegates,properties,notifications grab some basic tutorial try http://raywenderlich.com/

Comment: Read book programming in objective-c by stephen kochan , it will clear your basics. Plus , ray wenderlich tutorials.